# Bash/Awk - Store in a variable part of one argument

Tags: bash, loops, awk, arguments

For a given script I can supply one argument that has the following form:
-u[number][letter][...]

Examples: -u2T34T120F -u1T2T10F

Letters are either T or F, and the number is an integer number, which can be up to 999.

I would like a write loop where in each iteration the number is stored in variable "a" and the corresponding letter in variable "b". The loop goes through all the number-letter pairs in the argument.

For the first example, the argument is **-u2T34T120F** the iterations would be:

- First: a=2 b=T
- Second: a=34 b=T
- Third: a=120 b=F

End of loop

Any suggestion is most welcome.

Comment: Are you talking about bash scripts+variables or awk scripts+variables? What are you going to do with the variables `a` and `b` after you populate them (as variables might not be the best approach vs arrays)?

Comment: Your problem would be a lot easier if you just supplied the pairs as arguments. `./wrapper <<<$'2 T\n 34 T\n 120 F'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ var='-u2T34T120F'

$ a=($(grep -o '[0-9]*' <<< "$var"))

$ b=($(grep -o '[TF]' <<< "$var"))

$ echo ${a[0]} ${a[1]} ${a[2]}
2 34 120

$ echo ${b[0]} ${b[1]} ${b[2]}
T T F
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do it with GNU awk:

```
<<<"2T34T120F" \
awk -v RS='[TF]' 'NF { printf "a: %3d  b: %s\n", $0, RT }'
```

Output:

```
a:   2  b: T
a:  34  b: T
a: 120  b: F
```

To use this in a bash while-loop do something like this:

```
<<<"2T34T120F" \
awk 'NF { print $0, RT }' RS='[TF]' |
while read a b; do 
  echo Do something with $a and $b 
done
```

Output:

```
Do something with 2 and T
Do something with 34 and T
Do something with 120 and F
```

Comment: Nice, could you explain this approach in some detail? Thanks

Comment: @B3y0nd3r - you do understand that, unlike every other solution posted so far, this one does not do what you asked for (save values in variables a and b), right? If what this solution does is what you really want then there's some alternatives that you should consider but no-one else guessed from your question that this is what you really wanted.

Comment: @B3y0nd3r: This sets the record separator (`RS`) to the letters you want to split the fields at. Thus `$0` will be set to the numbers and `RT` will be the following letter.

Comment: @EdMorton: I wasn't sure exactly what the OP wanted, but I think this is an interesting approach to the field-splitting problem he is dealing with.

Comment: @EdMorton : You're right. Although this solution is useful in a sense, it does not store values in the relevant variables. Thanks anyway

Comment: @B3y0nd3r: I've added a way to successively set `a` and `b` in a bash while loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can use parameter expansion in bash:

```
#! /bin/bash

set -- -u2T34T120F       # Set the $1.

string=${1#-u}           # Remove "-u".
while [[ $string ]] ; do
    a=${string%%[FT]*}   # Everything before the first F or T.
    string=${string#$a}  # Remove the $a from the beginning of the string.
    b=${string%%[0-9]*}  # Everything before the first number.
    string=${string#$b}  # Remove the $b from the beginning of the string.
    echo $a $b
done
```

Or, using the same technique, but with arrays:

```
a=(${string//[TF]/ })   # Remove letters.
b=(${string//[0-9]/ })  # Remove numbers.
for (( i=0; i<${#a[@]}; i++ )) ; do
    echo ${a[i]} ${b[i]}
done
```

Answer (score 2):

how about this:

```
kent$  while IFS=' '  read a b; do echo "we have a:$a,b:$b\n---"; done<<< $(echo '-u2T34T120F'|sed 's/^-u//;s/[TF]/ &\n/g')
we have a:2,b:T
---
we have a:34,b:T
---
we have a:120,b:F
---
```

clear version:

```
while IFS=' '  read a b
do 
    echo "we have a:$a,b:$b\n---"; 
done<<< $(echo '-u2T34T120F'|sed 's/^-u//;s/[TF]/ &\n/g')
```